# Save react-pdf rendered file to state for sending it to server

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

So I am using react-pdf/renderer to generate a pdf on React client side. Now when the user presses a button, the generated file should be sent to the server as a file.

Now I am using **pdf** provided by the react-pdf/renderer

```
 setFile(pdf(<PdfReport/>))
```

this gives the error **cannot convert object to primitive types** when I append this file to formdata.
I converted this file to blob and then to a file

```
 setFile(pdf(<PdfReport/>).toBlob());
 var pdf = new File([file], "filename");
```

and when I send this to the server, I get a pdf file with only this

```
[object Promise]
```

I don't know how to convert the pdf generated to file to be able to send to server.